# Consecutive rising sequence of largest prime factors

Tags: nt.number-theory

I hope this is okay for the site, I asked on [math exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991248/consecutive-rising-sequence-of-largest-prime-factors) with no answer.

Consider the function $f(n)$ defined on the natural integers which returns the largest prime factor of $n$, and is $0$ for $1$. For example, $f(9)=3$,$f(15)=5$.

A beautiful riddle says that there are infinitely many $n$ so that $f(n)<f(n+1)<f(n+2)$.

I have 2 questions:

1.Given $k$, are there infinitely many $n$ so that $f(n)<f(n+1)...<f(n+k)$?

2.How often is $f(n)<f(n+1)$?

I'd guess is true because we can take large primes that are near each other, and with chinese reminder theorm make $n+i$ be divisible by $p_i$ and hope that after we divide all the other prime factors are small.

Proof of the riddle:

Lemma 1, if $f(a)<c, f(b)<c$, then $f(ab)<c$.

For any odd prime $q$ we find such different $n$, as there are infinitely many different odd primes we're done.

Choose an odd prime $q$, try $n+1=q$. Obviously $f(n)<f(n+1)$.

If $f(n+1)<f(n+2)$ we're done. Otherwise, choose $n+1$=$q^2$. Now $f(n)=f(q^2-1)=f((q−1)(q+1))$, so by lemma 1, by setting $a=q-1$, $b=q+1$, $c=q$  we get $f(n)<f(n+1)$. Again if $f(n+1)<f(n+2)$ we're done, otherwise choose $n+1=q^4$ and keep going like that. Assume by contradiction this goes on forever, then $q=f(q^{2^k})>f(q^{2^k}+1)$ for all $k$, but $gcd(q^{2^k}+1,q^{2^m}+1) = 1$ for all different $m,n$, and so eventually they contain primes larger than $q$, contradiction.

Comment: The function $f(n)$ is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A006530 with many references and links.

Comment: Also related are http://oeis.org/A070087 ($P(n) > P(n+1)$ where $P(n)$  is the largest prime factor of $n$.) and http://oeis.org/A070089 ($P(n) < P(n+1)$ where $P(n)$  is the largest prime factor of $n$.).

Comment: http://oeis.org/A079749 is the sequence this question is asking about.

Comment: Or possibly http://oeis.org/A100384 , the difference being whether or not you count e.g. the smallest run of 8 as being the same as the smallest run of 9 (the smallest run of 9 occurs before the smallest run of 8!)

Comment: @user104593 I'm not so confident about the CRT argument for the general case. If you're using CRT to solve congruences modulo 10 primes then in general the size of the smallest solution will be of the order of magnitude of the product of these primes, so you have lost control of the size of the other prime factors. It seems from OEIS that no run is known with $k=15$ (and the smallest example, assuming one exists, starts with a number bigger than $10^{13}$). One might instead wonder whether existence of long runs follows from standard conjectures on primes.

Comment: @KevinBuzzard Oh I absolutely agree it's not convincing, I just felt bad not to provide any progress because I had none :P

Comment: Erdos and Pomerance, On the largest prime factors of $n$ and $n+1$, Aequationes Mathematicae 17 (1978) 311-321 give the same construction of infinitely many triples with $f(n)<f(n+1)<f(n+2)$. "On the other hand, we cannot find infinitely many $n$ for which [$f(n)>f(n+1)>f(n+2)$], but perhaps we overlook a simple proof." A proof is given by Balog, On triplets with descending largest prime factors, Studia Sci Math Hungar 38 (2001) 45-50 (but I wouldn't call it a simple proof).

Comment: As partial progress towards question 2, it might be noted that in the same paper Gerry mentions, Erdos and Pomerance show that the inequality $f(n) < f(n+1)$ holds on a set of positive lower density, and the same for $f(n) > f(n+1)$.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281780/k-factorazy-tuples/281805#281805

Answer (score 5):

As **Kevin Buzzard** suggests in a comment,
this would be a consequence of one of the
"standard conjectures on primes", namely the 
[first
Hardy-Littlewood conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#First_Hardy.E2.80.93Littlewood_conjecture)
(which is the special case of 
[Schinzel's
hypothesis H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H) where all the polynomials are linear).
If $N$ is sufficiently divisible, say $N = {\rm lcm}(1,2,3,\ldots,k)^2$,
then each of $(Nx-i)/i$ for $i=1,2,3,\ldots,k$
is a linear polynomial in $x$ that always takes
integer values not divisible by any prime $\leq k$,
so Hardy-Littlewood predicts the existence of infinitely many $x$such that each of these $(Nx-i)/i$ is prime; then the largest prime factors of
the $k$ integers in $[Nx-k,Nx)$ are in increasing order.
The same argument applied to $(Nx+i)/i$ would likewise produce
infinitely many runs of $k$ integers $Nx+i$ ($i=1,\ldots,k$)
whose largest prime factors are $(Nx+i)/i$ and are thus in decreasing order.

Answer (score 1):

I think at this point it is safe to say that the answer to question 1 is, conjecturally yes but nothing has been proved for any $k\ge3$, and the answer to question 2 is, conjecturally half the time (in the limit, as $n\to\infty$) but this too has not been proved.