# factorazy $k$-tuples

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let us call $k$-tuple $(n+1,n+2,..,n+k)$ a *factorazy* $k$-tuple if we have $p(n+1)<p(n+2)<\cdots<p(n+k)$ where $p(m)$ denotes biggest prime factor of $m$.

I would like to know:

> Is it true that for every $k \in \mathbb N \setminus \{1\}$ there exists at least one *factorazy* $k$-tuple? If not, what is the maximal value of $k$? For which $k$´s there exist an infinite number of *factorazy* $k$-tuples? What is known about this topic?

Comment: $p(n)$ is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A006530 with a link to a listing up to $n=100,000$. $p(8)<\cdots<p(11)$; $p(90)<\cdots<p(94)$; $p(168)<\cdots<p(173)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Do you expect $k$-factorazy tuples to exist for every $k$?

Comment: Honestly, my opinions on such a question are worth nothing.

Comment: Smallest $m$ such that $p(m)<\cdots<p(m+k-1)$ are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A100384, e.g., $p(256994754033)<\cdots<p(256994754047)$. http://oeis.org/A079749 is closely related.

Comment: The question is very close to, perhaps a duplicate of, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261640/consecutive-rising-sequence-of-largest-prime-factors

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, it is very similar in spirit.

Answer (score 5):

The $k=3$ case is solved in Erdos & Pomerance, On the largest prime factors of $n$ and $n+1$, Aequationes Mathematicae 17 (1978) 311-321, available [here](https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper17.pdf). The solution is short enough to give here in its entirety. Let $P(n)$ be the largest prime factor of $n$, let $p$ be an odd prime, and $$k_0=\inf\{\,k:P(p^{2^k}+1)>p\,\}$$ (note that $P(p^{2^{k_0}}+1)\equiv1\bmod{2^{k_0+1}}$, so $k_0<\infty$). Then $$P(p^{2^{k_0}}-1)<P(p^{2^{k_0}})<P(p^{2^{k_0}}+1)$$ and we're done.

Some variants are discussed elsewhere in the paper, and also at B46 in Guy, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, 3rd edition.

Answer (score 3):

If we assume the prime $k$-tuples conjecture, then there are infinitely many such tuples for any fixed $k$. To see this, consider the $k$ polynomials with integer coefficients:
$$
k!x-1, \quad\frac{k!}2x-1, \quad\frac{k!}3x-1, \quad\dots\quad, \frac{k!}kx-1.
$$
The product of these polynomials has no common prime factor (check $x=0$), so conjecturally there are infinitely many integers $x$ such that the above expressions are simultaneously prime. But then
$$
k!x-1, \quad k!x-2 = 2\bigg( \frac{k!}2x-1 \bigg), \quad k!x-3 = 3\bigg( \frac{k!}3x-1 \bigg), \quad\dots
$$
form such a tuple (with, I guess, $n=k!x-k-1$).

Of course the infinitude of primes proves that there are infinitely many such $2$-tuples. I don't know offhand whether the $k=3$ case is known, although it doesn't seem out of the question.

Comment: k=3 would follow if there is an infinite number of Mersenne primes of the form 6m-5 and if we agree that 1 is prime (in this context)